# ID3DX11Texture2D pixel data

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I'm trying to get the back buffer pixel data in DX11 in order to save it to a file.
Is there any way to get the pixel data of a ID3D11Texture2D without having to create a view for it and then get the resource from the view ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I need: [ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476392%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the texture and then copy from it.  However, the bits coming back may be implementation-dependent.  Also, not every GPU allows you to mess with the back buffers, especially if things like FSAA is on...

In these cases, for dynamic screen-shots, you usually create a RenderTarget surface and then render into it.

Comment: Well all I'm trying to do is memcpy the back buffer into another texture so that when the app closes I can save multiple screenshots. Things is if I juste create a RenderTarget, when the app closes all the RenderTargets point to the same back buffer which contains the last image.

Comment: @dotminic, you probably confuses RenderTarget with the backbuffer.  They are separate.  You create a (n) RenderTarget surfaces, and render into them.  The pictures don't change afterwards.  You get (n) textures with different screen-shots.

Comment: This answer is too abstract. Clearly the question is about ID3D11Texture2D, so how does one "lock the texture and copy from it"? I'm familiar with DX9, myself, and am looking for this exact answer. And as far as I can tell, there is no immediate "lock", as there was LockRect in DX9.